# Apply a real example to divide-and-conquer algorithm

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

This question comes from Levitin, A. Introduction to the Design and Analysis of Algorithms. Pearson. Exercise 5.1 Q1.

Write  pseudocode for a divide-and-conquer algorithm for finding the position of the largest element in an array of n numbers.

The solution given is as below:

```
function MaxIndex(A, l, r)
if l = r return l
else temp1 <- MaxIndex(A, l, (l+r)/2 )
     temp2 <- MaxIndex(A, (l+r)/2+1, r)
     if A[temp1] >= A[temp2]
         return temp1
     else return temp2
```

**However, I meet some problem when I use a random example to understand this algorithm**

For example, I have an array **A[20, 10, 30, 15,6]** at position 0 to 4

```
function MaxIndex (A[.], l=0, r=4)
if l=r return l  // pass
else temp1 <- MaxIndex(A, l=0, (l+r)/2=(0+4)/2=2 ) // So MaxIndex (A, 0, 2)
     temp2 <- MaxIndex(A, ((l+r)/2)+1=((0+4)/2)+1 =3, r=4) // So MaxIndex(A,3,4)
     if A[temp1] >= A[temp2]
         return temp1
     else return temp2
```

then

```
function MaxIndex (A[.], l=0, r=2)
if l=r return l  // pass
else temp1_1 <- MaxIndex(A, l=0, (l+r)/2=(0+2)/2=1) // So MaxIndex (A, 0, 1)
     temp1_2 <- MaxIndex(A, ((l+r)/2)+1=((0+2)/2)+1 =2, r=2) // So MaxIndex(A,2,2)
     if A[temp1_1] >= A[temp1_2]
         return temp1_1
     else return temp1_2
```

then

```
function MaxIndex (A[.], l=0, r=1)
if l=r return l  // pass
else temp1_1_1 <- MaxIndex(A, l=0, (l+r)/2=(0+1)/2=0.5) // So MaxIndex (A, 0, 0.5)?????????
     temp1_1_2 <- MaxIndex(A, ((l+r)/2)+1=((0+1)/2)+1 =1.5, r=1) // So MaxIndex(A,1.5,1)??????????
     if A[temp1_1] >= A[temp1_2]
         return temp1_1
     else return temp1_2
```

**I feel like I cannot move any further since then. Maybe my understanding about apply this algorithm is wrong. Should I think by default, when either j or i is not an integer, round down to the nearest integer? And when ((1+r)/2)+1 > r, I will keep r value instead?**

Comment: In `(l+r)/2` the division is supposed to be the *integral* division, e.g. $(0+1)/2=0$. Or, in your words, you *should* round down. Does that help?

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yep, thank you for clarify! Still in this algorithm, to compute its time complexity, the solution assume n = 2^k.  Is that means I actually could assign any value to n as long as it could help me simpler the solution? Would you mind tell me when we think about n = 2^k and when we think about n -k =0? Thank you so much!

Comment: I am sorry I don't fully understand your question. Let's assume that it is obvious that the algorithm works faster if $n$ is smaller, so if you find out that for $n=2^k$ it does the calculation in about $O(k)=O(\log_2 n)$ steps, then for $2^{k-1}\lt n\le 2^k$ it still does it in at most $O(k)$ steps. Now, as $k-1\lt\log_2 n$, i.e. $k\lt\log_2 n + 1$, the algorithm is done in at most $O(\log_2 n + 1)=O(\log_2 n)$ (the "+1" doesn't change the asymptotics when $n\to\infty$).

Comment: And ... as a general rule, please don't ask whether you "think about $n=2^k$" or "think about $n-k=0$". There is no such rule. Instead, try to understand each proof, and within it, the *reason* why you use one or the other. Then see, in a new situation, whether the same (or a different) reason applies.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you so much. It's a very clear explanation. In this example, after the backward substitution, when n = 2^k, I get C(n) = C(2^k) = 2^k - 1. Can I then say the time complexity is O(2^k) or O(n) instead of O(log n) as you mentioned before? Or can I interchangeable using them?

Comment: Ah, terribly sorry! I did not actually look at the complexity of the algorithm *above*, and for some reason I assumed it to be $O(\log n)$. Yes, sure, it is actually $O(n)$. First you prove it for $n=2^k$ as you did, and then you can extend it to all the other cases. (Namely, if $2^{k-1}\lt n\le 2^k$ then the number of steps is between $2^{k-1}-1$ and $2^k-1$. with $n\le 2^k\lt 2n$ so the number of steps is at most $O(2n)=O(n)$ (the constant factor does not play the role for "Big O")). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you for clarify again. That's absolutely a good answer. I never thought about the way to apply this complexity to all the other cases. And now I knew it! Thank you.